# Postgres converting date formats on insert using trigger

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I have a script that will insert data into a postgres table the issue is the data has a date format of DD/MM/YYYY and this date style Isn't accepted - I cant change the date style as that only lasts a session ( is what I read). I have this function and trigger to change the date format but I get the error date/time field value out of range: "DD/MM/YYY"
could anyone help on what is wrong with the function/trigger to get the date format to work I've tried a few iterations of this and all give the same error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION format_date() 
RETURNS TRIGGER 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$
BEGIN 
    NEW.Invoice_Date = to_char(NEW.Invoice_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date;
    NEW.Due_Date = to_char(NEW.Due_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date;
    NEW.Paid_Date = to_char(NEW.Paid_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date;

RETURN NEW ;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER format_date
BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE format_date();
```

I've tried with to_date with and without the new. within the to_char and I've tried forcing it to date with ::date on the column. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: If the incoming dates are always going to be `DD/MM/YYYY` you can change `DateStyle` in [postgresql.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT) and make it 'permanent'.  This `to_char(NEW.Invoice_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date;` should probably be `to_date(NEW.Invoice_Date, 'DD/MM/YYYY)::date;`

Comment: Im trying to avoid changing the postgresql.conf so trying to change the date format

Comment: Well if all the dates are not coming in as `DD/MM/YYYY` formatted strings your trigger will fail. If they are all coming in as `DD/MM/YYYY` then the `postgresql.conf` change will save you a lot of work. Do you have control over how they are formatted before they are received at the database?

Comment: No control on how they come in. I just know that the preferred method would be one where changes to postgresql.conf aren't required

Comment: You don't need to change `postgresql.conf`, you can change that per user `alter user ... set datestyle = '...'`;`

Comment: You still have answered whether the dates will always come in as `DD/MM/YYYY` or not?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name say one user writes to the DB and another selects would both users need to be updated like this or just the user who writes? I can explore this method but would rather have the trigger to convert it ( so it can be reused in other scenarios over changing all users' date styles)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver dates should always be coming in as DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: You can't convert this in a trigger. The syntax error happens when the statement (and its values) is parsed. Long before it's actually executed and the trigger has a chance to fire.

Comment: Are the users going through your application? If so a solution would be to put a layer in that converts the date/times into ISO format before they get inserted/updated.

Comment: You need to realize that **all date data types are stored in an internal definition**. Thus the dates with  format '2021-10-04' (yyyy-mm-dd) and format '04-10-2021' (dd-mm-yyyy) are stored and processed internally exactly the same.  Please **do not store date data in anything other than date or timestamp**.  Now define your column as date/timestamp, and do any conversion on the insert or before. Trigger and function not needed, data properly stored without them.  Formats are user only for display output and conversion during input.

Comment: Note your statements are contradictory. You say you have no control how they come in but then that  they should be 'mm/dd/yyyy' - well that is control. They do not com in the proper way they do not get stored (DB throws and exception). Or as @AdrianKlaver convert them to a standard form before sending the database.